# How to handle Audio playing in React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, audio, redux

I am making an audio player. It has pause, rewind and time seek features. How and who should handle the audio element?

- I can put it aside the store. I cant put it directly on the state, since it might get cloned. Then when in the reducer I can interact with it. The problem is that if I need to sync the time slider with the audio I will need to constantly poll the store using an action. It also doesn't really makes sense semantically speaking.
- I can create a custom React component, Audio, which does everything I said. the problem isn't solved. How can I refresh the slider? I could poll but I really don't like this solution. Besides, unless I create a component that contains both audio and slider, I would still need to use redux to connect both.

So what is the most  redux way to handle audio with progress display?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Redux - it's all about the state and consistency.

Your goal is to keep in sync the song time and the progress bar.

I see two possible aproaches:

## 1. Keep everyting in the Store.

So you have to keep the song's current time (in seconds for instance) in the Store, because of there are a few dependend components and its hard to sync them without the Store.

You have few events those change the current time:

- The current time itself. For example on each 1 second.
- Rewind.
- Time seek.

On a time change you will dispatch an action and will update the Store with the new time. Thereby keeping current song's time all components will be in sync.

Managing the state in unidirectional data flow with actions dispatching, reducers and stores is the Redux way of implementing any component.

Here is a pseudo code of the #1 aproach:

```
class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {

    onPlay(second) {
        // Store song current time in the Store on each one second
        store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_CURRENT_SECOND', second });
    }

    onRewind(seconds) {
        // Rewind song current time
        store.dispatch({ type: 'REWIND_CURRENT_SECOND', seconds });
    }   

    onSeek(seconds) {
        // Seek song current time
        store.dispatch({ type: 'SEEK_CURRENT_SECOND', seconds });
    }

    render() {
        const { currentTime, songLength } = this.state;

        return <div>
            <audio onPlay={this.onPlay} onRewind={this.onRewind} onSeek={this.onSeek} />

            <AudioProgressBar currentTime songLength />
        </div>
    }
}
```

---

## 2. Keep as less as possible in the Store.

If the above aproach doesn't fit your needs, for example you may have a lot of Audio players on a same screen - there may be a performance gap.

In that case you can access your HTML5 audio tag and  components via [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in the componentDidMount lifecycle method.

The HTML5 audio tag has DOM events and you can keep the both components in sync without touching the Store. If there is a need to save something in the Store - you can do it anytime.

Please take a look at [react-audio-player source code](https://github.com/justinmc/react-audio-player/blob/master/src/index.jsx) and check how it handles the refs and what API the plugin exposes. For sure you can take inspiration from there. Also you can reuse it for your use case.

Here are some of the API methods those are related to your questions:

- onSeeked - Called when the user drags the time indicator to a new time. Passed the event.
- onPlay - Called when the user taps play. Passed the event.
- onPause - Called when the user pauses playback. Passed the event.
- onListen - Called every listenInterval milliseconds during playback. Passed the event.

---

## What approach should I use?

It depends to your use case specifics. However generally speaking in the both aproaches it's a good idea to implement a [presentational component](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components) with the necessary API methods and it's up to you to decide how much data to manage in the Store.

So I created a starting component for you to illustrate how to handle the refs to the audio and slider. Start / Stop / Seeking features included. For sure it has drawbacks, but as I already mentioned it's a good starting point.

You can evolve it to a presentational component with good API methods, that suits your needs.

```js
class Audio extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
   duration: null
  }
   };
 
 handlePlay() {
  this.audio.play();
 }
 
 handleStop() {
  this.audio.currentTime = 0;
  this.slider.value = 0;
  this.audio.pause(); 
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.slider.value = 0;
  this.currentTimeInterval = null;
  
  // Get duration of the song and set it as max slider value
  this.audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
   this.setState({duration: this.audio.duration});
  }.bind(this);
  
  // Sync slider position with song current time
  this.audio.onplay = () => {
   this.currentTimeInterval = setInterval( () => {
    this.slider.value = this.audio.currentTime;
   }, 500);
  };
  
  this.audio.onpause = () => {
   clearInterval(this.currentTimeInterval);
  };
  
  // Seek functionality
  this.slider.onchange = (e) => {
   clearInterval(this.currentTimeInterval);
   this.audio.currentTime = e.target.value;
  };
 }

 render() {
  const src = "https://mp3.gisher.org/download/1000/preview/true";
  
  
  return <div>
   <audio ref={(audio) => { this.audio = audio }} src={src} />
   
   <input type="button" value="Play"
    onClick={ this.handlePlay.bind(this) } />
   
   <input type="button"
     value="Stop"
     onClick={ this.handleStop.bind(this) } />
   
   <p><input ref={(slider) => { this.slider = slider }}
     type="range"
     name="points"
     min="0" max={this.state.duration} /> </p>
  </div>
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Audio />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

---

If you have any questions feel free to comment below! :)

Comment: If you need to have multiple players at the same time, you can give each player a unique id, pass that id in all actions and put everything in the store under the player id.

Comment: That's right! It's applicable to the both aproaches.

Comment: Nice thanks :) the imperative design seems better for this one, since this will not impact performance too much. I will still keep a few things in store but I will still use the state for a few things such as track ended...

Comment: Also, how can I pass from declarative code to imperative code. ie, suppose I have a AudioComponent which takes a track name, artist name  and audio url. How can make sure this component isn't destroyed when the state changes? How can I listen to state changes? For instance I want to change audio source, I would have something like that in my parent `<AudioPlayer audioURL={this.state.props.track.streamURL} />` and then somewhere in my code I would have an action called which would mutate the state using a reducer to change the URL.

Comment: If I understand correctly the way VirtualDOM works, some DOM elements would get destroyed by the state change right?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm blind. `shouldComponentUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` should help me. I get how you can handle pause (`<AudioPlayer paused ... />`) but how can I handle seek time feature? This isn't part of state, it is more of an action, since I want to  do it only once. A hack

Comment: A hacky way would be to generate a random number and set it as a prop along the time. For instance `<AudioPlayer time={state.time} />` where ` state.time` looks like this `1337#2e02A` (1337 is the time in ms, 2e02A the number). Then in my component I would  ensure that I dont set audio time unless number is new. But i dislike it

Comment: Hey, on a state change your component won't be destroyed, unless you explicity destroy or unmount it. For example let's say your `<AudioPlayer paused />` depends to `paused` state property. Once the property is changed, for instance from `false` to `true`, then the component will be rerendered. React Virtual DOM has a diff algorithm those calculates the differences and renders only the changes.

Comment: About time seek functionality. In my #1 aproach I keep current time of the song in the Store (in seconds). So imagine you have a seek button. Once clicked the song should go 5 seconds forward. Therefore you can dispatch an action (`store.dispatch({ type: 'SEEK_CURRENT_SECOND',  5});`) that adds 5 seconds to the song current time in the Store.

Comment: Open source education is so powerfull. My advice is to review the code of some open source plugins. Did you check / review [react-audio-player](https://github.com/justinmc/react-audio-player) plugin? [Its source code](https://github.com/justinmc/react-audio-player/blob/master/src/index.jsx) perfectly response to my *What approach should I use?* section in the answer.

You can install the plugin locally and get the best of it.

Comment: Yes i checked the plugin very interesting. The problem with #1 approach is that I would need to poll, reduce and mutate state, refresh Virtual DOM and DOM which would be hungry performance wise. Plus this would log a lot in the console, making it unusable. I am more interested with an imperative approach in a react component where the audio directly update the real DOM using `refs`. My question here is how can I then handle seek time. I dont need to know current time, shifting 5 secs isn't a feature, I only need to set time to 0 (externally, the range slider is internal to component).

Comment: I could use `<AudioComponent time={1337} url={...} />` to set time to 1337, and only use `componentWillUpdateProps` to determine if this is a new props and then setTime to audio (https://gist.github.com/vinz243/9bd02c27cfc310c8c2299b0f50c60efc). There are two main problems with this: first it does not work if you set time twice to 0 (restart track twice). Secondly, it isn't representative of the current state (where the audio is playing, thus time > 0). the first one I can remedy by setting a Math.random time between 0 and 1, but seems a little 'hacky'.

Comment: I've created a fiddle for you that's a good starting point for creating  an Audio presentational component. It has Play / Stop / Seek features. For seeking please click somewhere on the slider. *For sure it has some unexpected edge cases, but as I already mentioned - it's a good starting point*. https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/Lpydnrk0/

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot that was more or less what I planned to do. My question is how can I seek time from outside the component. Say I have a button "Previous Track", which, when clicked either goes back to previous track if current time is under 2s, or goes back to the beginning of the track. The button isn't necessarily next to the range, so it's outside of my AudioComponent. How can I do that?

Comment: But nvm I wont implement this functionality

Comment: You can expose a method from `<Audio />` component and call it from the parent. [Here's the documentation](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html). Keep in mind that breaks `<Audio />` component encapsulation and it's not a good practise to use it everytime (only if there aren't better solutions).

Another option is to have `seek` Store property. It'll be an array and there you will push +- seconds. So you can pass `seek` array to the `<Audio seek={this.state.seek} />`. In the <Audio /> you will handle `seek` property changes.

Comment: @JordanEnev Thanks man, you saved my life. This solution works very well :)

Comment: Hey @JordanEnev I know it's an old answer, but now I want to implement a forward Song Reducer now in `initial_state` should i use the current index song i saved before in the redux store, so how can i get the existing state in redux to use it as the initial state in `forward Song Reducer`?

Comment: Hey @OliverD, it would be better to open a new SO question and providing more implementation details there. Here, I don't know your setup and what exactly you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple React solution

In order to keep audio player in sync with rest of the app you can use classic React **props down events up** data flow. That means you keep your state in parent component and pass it to children components as props, along with event handlers that modify the state. More specifically, in your state you can have:

- `seekTime`: this will be used to force time update on your player
- `appTime`: this will be broadcasted by your player and passed to other components in order to keep them in sync with player.

An example implementation might look like this:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  // we'll define state in parent component:
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [seekTime, setSeekTime] = useState(0); // forces player to update its time
  const [appTime, setAppTime] = useState(0); // dictated by player, broadcasted to other components

  // state will be passed as props and setter function will allow child components to change state:
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPlaying(true)}>PLAY</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPlaying(false)}>PAUSE</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSeekTime(appTime - 5)}>-5 SEC</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSeekTime(appTime + 5)}>+5 SEC</button>
      <Seekbar
        value={appTime}
        min="0"
        max={duration}
        onInput={(event) => setSeekTime(event.target.value)}
      />
      <Player
        playing={playing}
        seekTime={seekTime}
        onTimeUpdate={(event) => setAppTime(event.target.currentTime)}
        onLoadedData={(event) => setDuration(event.target.duration)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Seekbar({ value, min, max, onInput }) {
  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      step="any"
      value={value}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      onInput={onInput}
    />
  );
}

function Player({ playing, seekTime, onTimeUpdate, onLoadedData }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  if (ref.current) playing ? ref.current.play() : ref.current.pause();
  //updates audio element only on seekTime change (and not on each rerender):
  useEffect(() => (ref.current.currentTime = seekTime), [seekTime]);
  return (
    <audio
      src="./your.file"
      ref={ref}
      onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
      onLoadedData={onLoadedData}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Redux-like solution

If you prefer a redux-like solution, you can move your app's state to a reducer function and rewrite the parent component like this:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

// define reducer and initial state outside of component
const initialState = { playing: false, duration: 0, seekTime: 0, appTime: 0 };
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "play":
      return { ...state, playing: true };
    case "pause":
      return { ...state, playing: false };
    case "set-duration":
      return { ...state, duration: action.value };
    case "set-time":
      return { ...state, appTime: action.value };
    case "seek":
      return { ...state, seekTime: action.value };
    default:
      throw new Error("Unhandled action " + action.type);
  }
}

function App() {
  // use reducer and dispatch instead of state
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "play" })}>PLAY</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "pause" })}>PAUSE</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "seek", value: state.appTime + 5 })}
      >
        -5 SEC
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "seek", value: state.appTime + 5 })}
      >
        +5 SEC
      </button>
      <Seekbar
        value={state.appTime}
        min="0"
        max={state.duration}
        onInput={(event) =>
          dispatch({ type: "seek", value: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      <Player
        playing={state.playing}
        seekTime={state.seekTime}
        onTimeUpdate={(event) =>
          dispatch({ type: "set-time", value: event.target.currentTime })
        }
        onLoadedData={(event) =>
          dispatch({ type: "set-duration", value: event.target.duration })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// The rest of app doesn't need any change compared to previous example. 
// That's due to decoupled architecture!
function Seekbar({ value, min, max, onInput }) {
  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      step="any"
      value={value}
      min={min}
      max={max}
      onInput={onInput}
    />
  );
}

function Player({ playing, seekTime, onTimeUpdate, onLoadedData }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  if (ref.current) playing ? ref.current.play() : ref.current.pause();
  useEffect(() => (ref.current.currentTime = seekTime), [seekTime]);
  return (
    <audio
      src="./your.file"
      ref={ref}
      onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
      onLoadedData={onLoadedData}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Passing DOM ref around the app?

It might be tempting to simply pass a ref to DOM audio element around the app instead of implementing proper state management. However this solution would couple your components together and thus make your app harder to maintain. So unless you really really need the 3 miliseconds taken by React's virtual DOM (and in most cases you don't), **I would advise against doing it**.