# Reactjs how to call a function every second to update the component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an audio player in Reactjs. How can I call a function each second to update a progress bar and a timer? When I call playAudio a second time it updates my progress bar and time_played, but it won't refresh each second as it should.
What should I change/add in my code?

```
updateProgress(audio) {

    if(audio) {
        audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        audio.currentTime = audio.duration * this.state.progress;
        this.setState({
            time_total: audio.duration,
            time_played: this.state.audio.currentTime,
            progress: this.state.audio.currentTime / this.state.audio.duration
        });
        console.log('time total', this.state.time_total);
        console.log('time played', this.state.time_played);
        console.log('progress', this.state.progress);
    });
    }
}

playAudio(playing_url) {
    let audio = new Audio(playing_url);

    this.updateProgress(audio);

    if(!this.state.playing) {
        audio.play();
        this.setState({
            playing: true,
            playing_story: playing_url,
            audio
        });
    } else {
        if(this.state.playing_story === playing_url) {
            this.state.audio.pause();
            this.setState({
                playing: false
            });
        } else {
            this.state.audio.pause();
            audio.play();
            this.setState({
                playing: true,
                playing_story: playing_url,
                audio,
                progress: 0
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer => [How to handle Audio playing in React & Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42754114/4312466). I'm sure it will give you some key references.

Comment: you could call `this.updateProgress(audio);` in setInterval like 
`setInterval(() => { this.updateProgress(audio); }, 1000)`

Comment: and the setInterval should be in playAudio()?