# Working with Audio objects in React/ Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, redux

I'm currently building a music app and have a question on the correct way to approach audio objects in terms of storing them and their current state in React/ Redux.

I'm currently dispatching an action in one of my components that's going to the following reducer to set an audio object as part of the state:

**Reducer.js**

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
  audioTrack: false
});

export const musicPlayer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK': {
      const mergeObj = {};
      const audioTrack = state.get('audioTrack');
      mergeObj.audioTrack = audioTrack;
      if (!audioTrack) {
        mergeObj.audioTrack = new Audio('../../public/music/test.mp3');
        mergeObj.audioTrack.play();
      } else if (state.get('audioTrack').paused) {
        mergeObj.audioTrack.play();
      } else {
        mergeObj.audioTrack.pause();
      }
      return state.merge(mergeObj);
    }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

Basically here if `audioTrack` is `false` i'm creating a new audio track when someone clicks a play button. I'm then adding the `audioTrack` object to the reducers state. From there if the track is set then I can access the `audioTrack` object from the reducers state and pause it if I need to as well as call whatever other audio methods I need to.

My issue here is that i'm pretty sure storing the audio object in a reducer is not the correct way to approach something like this. The audio object has some deep nested objects and I would like to keep my reducers as flat as possible for obvious performance reasons.

What would be a better way to approach this? I've though of adding the audio object to the window object and just store its' state there but again not sure if this is the most reasonable approach. Would like to keep any audio elements out of the dom to prevent users from doing a quick inspect element and find the node along with its' source.

Thanks and please let me know if anythings unclear!

Comment: Maybe just store the id/url of the audio, then play/pause it in your component? Why store it in reducer at all? Can everything be done through local component state?

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42754114/4312466

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the approach to change the type of a state key (`audioObject` from `boolean` to `class Audio`) is not a recommended approach. You should refrain from changing the type of a state key as it can lead to many unforeseen bugs. It is also difficult for a human reader to figure out its use while skimming through the code.

Now, seeing your use-case (keeping track of only a single audio at a time), I feel that separation of concerns is not really clear in your current code which is why the confusion whether audioTrack should be maintained in a component or reducer state. Let's improve upon that using Redux.

We will apply Separation of Concerns in following way.

1. What actions are available: See `actionCreator`
2. What is your state structure: See `initialState` in reducer
3. How is your state updated:  See `musicPlayer` in reducer
4. What does your app look like: Your presentational concerns and side-effects will be taken care of in your React component. It will be wrapped with `connect` to subscribe to Redux state.
5. How does your component interpret the Redux state?: See `mapStateToProps`

Your **Redux state** will have 2 keys:

1. `audioTrack`: keeps track of active audio track's file name.
2. `isPlaying`: keeps track of whether track is playing or paused.

Your **actionCreator** will look like this:

```
// sets active track    
export const setActiveTrack (activeTrack) => ({
    type: 'musicPlayer/SET_ACTIVE_TRACK',
    payload: activeTrack,
});

// plays active track    
export const playTrack () => ({
    type: 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK',
    payload: true,
});

// pauses active track    
export const pauseTrack () => ({
    type: 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK',
    payload: false,
});
```

Your **reducer** will work as follows:

```
//always use null as an indicator of empty.
const initialState = {
    audioTrack: null, 
    isPlaying: false,
};

export const musicPlayer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'musicPlayer/SET_ACTIVE_TRACK': 
    return {
        ...state,
        audioTrack: action.payload,
    }
    case 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK':
    return {
        ...state,
        isPlaying: action.payload,
    }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

Your **mapStateToProps** will look like so:

```
mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        audioTrack: createSelector(state.audioTrack, audioTrack => new Audio(audioTrack)), // `createSelector` will return the same old Audio instance unless the `audioTrack` value changes
        isPlaying: state.isPlaying
    }
}
```

Finally your **presentational component**:

```
// Take care of side-effects in componentDidMount (for first render) or componentDidUpdate (for all other renders)
componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.props.audioTrack) {
        const audioTrack = this.props.audioTrack;
        if(this.props.isPlaying) audioTrack.play();
        else audioTrack.pause();
    }
}
render() {
    return ...; // your presentation logic
}
```

Playing/pausing an audio file is a side-effect which should be taken care of in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` according to React 16 guidelines. You can check that out in the `Notes` section here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Wrapping an audio file with an Audio Class is done in `mapStateToProps` using `reselect/createSelector` because `createSelector` will return the older Audio file if the value of `state.audioTrack` has not changed. This is required for pausing after playing an audio file.

createSelector: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc

(I have assumed here that the user will work only on a single file at a time. Once, he changes the audio file, it can be discarded. In case, you want to maintain a list of active audio files, you can use a generator function which generates the audio given the file name.)

**Performance**

As long as perf is concerned, you need not worry about the large Audio object. Its reference is not stored anywhere except by `createSelector`. When the user changes the active audio track, the older track will be free to be collected in the next GC cycle.

**Scalability**

1. *Flexibility to add more attributes*: If you want to add more attributes, you can store them in state but do remember to store only those attributes which actually affect your component state. For every change in your Redux state, your Reducer will be called and so will your `mapStateToProps`. This will lead to use-less re-rendering of your components if not used carefully.
2. *Presentation is independent of state logic*: In the future, if you want to change just the presentation logic of your component (like using another class instead of Audio), you don't have to worry about changing your reducer code.
3. *Reducer is independent of how data is being consumed*: The reducer is independent of the structure of the audio file. It gives you the flexibility of using the same Reducer code in another audio component you may write (for example you need to write a separate component for mobile apps). It's always a good practice to separate your data and state concerns from your presentation concerns.

I will recommend checking out this Video series by Redux Creator Dan Abramov to understand how to use Redux: https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

I have demonstrated how to integrate your use-case using Redux as I got an idea that you are trying to learn Redux. But for such a simple application, you might not need Redux. You can simply use the concept of Container (data/state) and presentational components. Check out this amazing article by Dan Abramov: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 4):

Do not store it in redux' state.

1. The whole audio object is **redundant** information (name/path to file, play/pause state, a current time information is sufficient).
2. Redux and immutable approach are not really suitable for this type of objects in performance point of view.
3. And, this type of objects is not suitable to work with redux dev tools/logger/human eyes.

You have to store a minimal amount of information about audio. So, any component can subscribe to this state. For example, instantiate the audio object on `componentDidMount` and store it in local state, switch audio on `getDerivedStateFromProps/componentWillReceiveProps`, destroy audio object on `componentWillUnmount`, etc.

Also, if you want to hide the information about the audio, then it is yet another reason to use component's local state.

Comment: I hear your suggestion but i'm still a bit concerned that storing the audio object in the local state of a component instead of a Redux reducer could still impact performance as it's such a large object. Do you think this is the case? Also if I only store certain attributes about the audio object, how can I refer to it again without having to insert it in the DOM?

Comment: Storing the audio object itself has no impact on performance, regardless of whether it's in the Redux store, local component state, or an instance field on the component.  However, @amankkg is correct that since the audio object is non-serializable, it shouldn't actually be kept in the Redux store.  You should write a React component that reads the data from the store, then uses React's lifecycle methods to drive the imperative audio API.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here how I did it ,First make an Audio Component like so

```
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import styles from '../../app.sass'
import isUndefined from 'lodash/isUndefined'
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {setActiveTrack} from "../../containers/Audio/actions";


class Audio extends PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    const { src, controlsList, preload, controls, autoPlay } = props
    this.state = {
      src: src,
      controlsList: isUndefined(controlsList) ? 'nodownload' : controlsList,
      preload: isUndefined(preload) ? 'none' : preload,
      controls: isUndefined(controls) ? true : controls,
      autoPlay: isUndefined(autoPlay) ? false : autoPlay,
    }
  }

  setActiveTrackHandler = () => {
    const { dispatch, uid } =this.props
    dispatch(setActiveTrack(uid))
  }


  render () {
    const {uid, audioTrack} =this.props
    if (this.audioRef && uid !== audioTrack) {
      this.audioRef.pause()
    }
    return (
      <audio
        ref={audio => this.audioRef = audio}
        controls={this.state.controls}
        preload={this.state.preload}
        autoPlay={this.state.autoPlay}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        controlsList={this.state.controlsList}
        onPlay={this.setActiveTrackHandler}
      >
        <source src={this.state.src} />
      </audio>
    )
  }

}


function mapStateToProps (state){
  return {
    audioTrack: state.audioReducer.audioTrack
  }
}

const AudioClass = CSSModules(Audio,styles, { allowMultiple: true })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AudioClass)
```

Then here would be your Constants

```
export const SET_ACTIVE_TRACK = 'containers/Audio/SET_ACTIVE_TRACK'
```

And here is your Actions

```
import {
  SET_ACTIVE_TRACK,
  PLAY_TRACK
} from './constants'

// sets active track
export function setActiveTrack (activeTrack) {
  return {
    type: SET_ACTIVE_TRACK,
    payload: activeTrack
  }

}
```

and here is the Reducer

```
import {
  SET_ACTIVE_TRACK
} from './constants'



const initialState = {
  audioTrack: null,
  isPlaying: false,
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

  case SET_ACTIVE_TRACK:
    return {
      ...state,
      audioTrack: action.payload,
    }

  default: return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```