# Redux architecture for audio player and handling errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I am building an audio player which consists of a control panel, where user can pause/play currently selected track, and audio players themselves.
Possible actions are to pause/play the track, and the audio player component is listening to state changes and deciding whether to play/pause the track (example code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880480/18547676)

```
Actions:

// plays active track    
export const playTrack () => ({
    type: 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK',
    payload: true,
});

// pauses active track    
export const pauseTrack () => ({
    type: 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK',
    payload: false,
});

Reducer:

const initialState = {
    isPlaying: false,
};

export const musicPlayer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'musicPlayer/PLAY_TRACK':
    return {
        ...state,
        isPlaying: action.payload,
    }
    default: return state
  }
}

Component (state mapped to props):

componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.props.audioTrack) {
        // What to do in case audioTrack.play() errors out?
        if(this.props.isPlaying) audioTrack.play();
        else audioTrack.pause();
    }
}
```

My question is the following; what is the recommended way to handle the cases when for example, audio player could not execute the action due to error. For example, user wanted to pause the current player; state changed, and audio player received the update, but was unable to perform the action due to error (in which case Redux state and the actual player state are not in sync). Is there some pattern to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the actual audio player you're using. The browser's native one for example has the option to attach event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/onerror

You could use this to sync error state with redux:

```
audioElem.onerror = () => {
    dispatch(setError(audioElem.error);
};
```

The general idea would be that if the audio interface emits events, you dispatch redux actions. And user interaction, like pressing a play button, dispatches actions that call methods on the audio interface as a side effect (example using thunk middleware):

```
const playAction = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(playRequested());
    try {
        await audioElem.play();
        dispatch(playStarted());
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(playFailed(error));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate further on this? Why do you set a local state in the first example? In your second example, how would the state in Redux look like, and how would it be modified when calling playRequested/Started/Failed? Would each command need requested/started/failed actions?

Comment: @circle1452 The first example is not really local state, it's just a reference to an `<audio>` element ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio ). You can't put it in redux, it should probably be kept in a central place in your app. In the second example, the state would just be a simple boolean flag `state.isPlaying`. The audio API works with promises that can be fulfilled (then audio is playing) or rejected (error occurred when trying to play audio). There is a short delay when pressing play, it is not instant (then the API would be synchronous).

Comment: If the state is a simple boolean (isPlaying), what is the point of dispatch(playRequested/Started/Failed)? I guess some additional state is needed?

Comment: @circle1452 In case you want to block the play button from being clicked again, or display a loading indicator. If you don't need this information, `playRequested` is obsolete of course.

Comment: I would like to have the loading information too. I was wondering if somehow request, failure, success could somehow be applied in this case?

Comment: @circle1452 Yes, It's the same principle, an async operation that starts at some point and that results in success or failure. So you could use redux-toolkits `createAsyncThunk` for example (originally meant for the http request use case).

Comment: I would appreciate if you could help with the structure of the state, in case something like that is used.

Comment: @circle1452 I don't know what kind of features you have in mind, I can't build this for you. My advice is to have a look at the audio API and play around with it. Once you know how to handle the native audio (or whichever player you end up using), you can follow the general pattern of mapping audio events to redux actions and mapping redux actions to audio player instance method calls as I showed in the snippets.